# Excel Validation to disallow percentage sign

Tags: excel, validation

I want to put up a validation that should not allow percentage sign in excel sheet. I tried the data validation option to select only decimals, but still when I put the percent sign at the end of the number, excel considers this. Please help

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/356346/925350) for some help on this.

Comment: I tried the option but excel still considers the percentage sign. It keeps converting the number into percentage

Comment: I think you have two issues working here. The first is to prevent the user from entering a percentage character (which the link above provides an answer to). The second issue is likely the cell is formatted to show the value as a percent -- in this case Excel puts the percent character in there for you. Change the cell format to Number and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in the Data-Validation as Formula:

```
=LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)<>"P"
```

Best regards chris

Comment: Sorry I always have to translate the formula from german to english and forgot to change the semicolon to comma. I correct the formula above.

Comment: @Raghu : Does it work for you now. If yes please vote the answert and mark this answer as solve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this VBA-solution can help:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim cell As Range

   For Each cell In Target

       If InStr(cell.Text, "%") > 0 Then
           cell.Value = ""
           MsgBox "It's not allowed to insert a %-sign", vbInformation
       End If

   Next

End Sub
```

This procedure will validate evry input and if a %-sign is inside, it will throw an message box with an error message.

If you are not familiar with VBA: You have to copy this procedute into the code-area of the sheet. Therefore open the Visual Basic Editor. On the left side you will find a list with your sheets. Double click on the sheet where you want to validate for a %-sign and copy the procedure into the code-area.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved.